# Drools Data Table to Drl File conversion - Empty Condition Column

Tags: datatables, drools

```
// rule values at C12, header at C7
rule "CalcInterest_12"
    salience 65524
    activation-group "all"
    when
        a:DroolsInput(RuleActivationFreezeDate > "15-Feb-2016")
        f:DroolsOutput()        
    then
        f.setCommission((a.getAmount() * 0.035 > 7500.00) ? 7500.00 :     a.getAmount() * 0.035);           
end
```

[image: Drools Datatable]

My requirement is to have two sets of variables which will reference to two different Java objects. One will be referenced in condition column to refer to the input values and the other will be referenced in action column which will set values to the object once the rules are run.

Shown above is Drl File generated from Data Table (Drools 6.3 Version - Non Guvnor), the only line I have to add manually was f:FinancialProjection. In another stackoverflow post, it was marked that variables can only be referenced from the condition column and hence was asked to created an empty condition column which will hold reference to an object (Java) which will be used in Action for setting values once the rule is run against the fact. However, when I ran the excel file through Excel to Drl conversion, the empty condition column translation did not happen. Please let me know if you could provide any pointers to the same.

EDIT:
@laune - Based on your suggestions, I have gotten two things to work -
a. Add a dummy condition column check which also became variable declaration, that can be referenced on the ACTION column. (f:DroolsOuput price > 0.00 is the dummy check added in the below spreadsheet)
b. Declare a local variable, that is again referenced in a different action to compute actual value that is to be set to Java POJO. (Declared a local variable feePercent that is referenced in other rules)

The working data-table is copied below for others to reference.
[image: Drools Dummy Column]

Answer (score 1):

You can use several techniques:

```
### 1st ###
CONDITION
f:DroolsOutput()
/*$param*/
for reference
x

### 2nd ###
CONDITION

f:DroolsOutput()
for reference
x

### 3rd ###
a:DroolsInput() f:DroolsOutput() 
RuleActivationFreezeDate > "$param"
need to reference DroolsOutput
15-Feb-2016
```

The third option is a hack and relies on the implementation, i.e., which pair of parentheses is used for inserting the constraints.

**With #1 and #2, you still have to insert something in the cells below the comment cell,** but note that you may merge Excel cells to reduce typing.

**Comments on your spreadsheet**
Column A isn't going to help - delete it. Column B: change according to 1st or 2nd, make sure to insert something in the cells B6 and B7. Cells C3 and D3 must me merged and filled with what you have in A3, add a pair of parentheses.

Comment: Hi laune, thank you for your response.. I've edited my question to include the Data table, when I generate Drl file from the spreadsheet, the f.DroolsOutput() is not being generated. Not sure what I'm missing, I'm guessing something trivial :-(

Comment: I have highlit some text in my answer and added comments on your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi laune, I've updated my question to reflect a working decision table. Let me know your comments. Now, my next target is to set value to an Object that is within an Object. [Composition] Need to find out how to do it via decision table.

Comment: Finally it made sense to me :-) Thanks @laune for your help on this.